# can xmonad's logHook be run at set intervals rather than in (merely) response to layout events?

Tags: haskell, statusbar, xmonad

I'm using `dynamicLogWithPP` from `XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog` together with dzen2 as a status bar under xmonad. One of the things I'd like to have displayed in the bar is the time remaining in the currently playing track in audacious (if any). Getting this information is easy:

```
audStatus :: Player -> X (Maybe String)
audStatus p = do
  info <- liftIO $ tryS $ withPlayer p $ do
                ispaused <- paused
                md <- getMetadataString
                timeleftmillis <- (-) <$> (getCurrentTrack >>= songFrames) <*> time
                let artist = md ! "artist"
                    title = md ! "title"
                    timeleft = timeleftmillis `quot` 1000
                    (minutes, seconds) = timeleft `quotRem` 60
                    disp = artist ++ " - " ++ title ++ " (-"++(show minutes)++":"++(show seconds)++")" -- will be wrong if seconds < 10
                    audcolor False = dzenColor base0  base03
                    audcolor True = dzenColor base1 base02 
                return $ wrap "^ca(1, pms p)" "^ca()" (audcolor ispaused disp)
  return $ either (const Nothing) Just info
```

So I can stick that in `ppExtras` and it works fine—*except* it only gets run when the `logHook` gets run, and that happens only when a suitable event comes down the pike. So the display is potentially static for a long time, until I (e.g.) switch workspaces.

It seems like some people just run two dzen bars, with one getting output piped in from a shell script. Is that the only way to have regular updates? Or can this be done from within xmonad (without getting too crazy/hacky)?

ETA: I tried this, which *seems* as if it should work better than it does:

1. create a TChan for updates from XMonad, and another for updates from a function polling Audacious;
2. set the `ppOutput` field in the `PP` structure from `DynamicLog` to write to the first TChan;
3. fork the audacious-polling function and have it write to the second TChan;
4. fork a function to read from both TChans (checking that they aren't empty, first), and combining the output.

Updates from XMonad are read from the channel and processed in a timely fashion, but updates from Audacious are hardly registered at all—every five or so seconds at best. It seems as if some approach along these lines ought to work, though.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit of explanation about why your proposed `TChan` solution -- and others based on having multiple threads -- doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I came here looking for an answer to this a few days ago, and I thought I'd share the way I solved it. You actually can do it entirely from xmonad. It's a tiny bit hacky, but I think it's much nicer than any of the alternatives I've come across.

Basically, I used the [XMonad.Util.Timer](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-Timer.html) library, which will send an X event after a specified time period (in this case, one second). Then I just wrote an event hook for it, which starts the timer again, and then manually runs the log hook.

I also had to use the [XMonad.Util.ExtensibleState](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-ExtensibleState.html) library, because Timer uses an id variable to make sure it's responding to the right event, so I have to store that variable between events.

Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import qualified XMonad.Util.ExtensibleState as XS
import XMonad.Util.Timer

...

-- wrapper for the Timer id, so it can be stored as custom mutable state
data TidState = TID TimerId deriving Typeable

instance ExtensionClass TidState where
  initialValue = TID 0

...

-- put this in your startupHook
-- start the initial timer, store its id
clockStartupHook = startTimer 1 >>= XS.put . TID

-- put this in your handleEventHook
clockEventHook e = do               -- e is the event we've hooked
  (TID t) <- XS.get                 -- get the recent Timer id
  handleTimer t e $ do              -- run the following if e matches the id
    startTimer 1 >>= XS.put . TID   -- restart the timer, store the new id
    ask >>= logHook.config          -- get the loghook and run it
    return Nothing                  -- return required type
  return $ All True                 -- return required type
```

Pretty straightforward. I hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: For anyone else using this code, you must also `import Data.Monoid`

Comment: This breaks the ability to restart xmonad for me: I'm assuming the restarted process can't handle events from the old process (not sure how those survive the process restart though). I had to extend it to stop firing when shutdown has been initiated and wait until the last event has been handled during shutdown.

Comment: @akosch Oh wow, I forgot about this question. Yes, it also keeps me from being able to restart, and I've changed my personal setup since I posted this answer. Nowadays I have a Conky instance sending an X event to xmonad once every second. The event contains hardware info, which I also display in dzen, but the point is I'm using an external program to trigger the update now. But if you got it working with restarts, maybe the answer should be updated with your code?

Comment: @DarthFennec Any chance you could share how you send this event from conky? I would be interested in doing something similar

Comment: @Dylan I wrote a separate program that starts Conky as a subprocess and reads its stdout. You can find it [here](https://github.com/DarthFennec/Miscellany/blob/master/XMoconk). It expects Conky to output lines of colon-separated integers (range 0-100), and each time it reads a line it parses out the ints and packs them into an X event, and sends it. It can also map a value to an exponential scale (which I use to to cap network usage values), and it can make sets of representative averages for arbitrarily many values (which I use for thermal reading samples, and this is most of the code).

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done from within xmonad; xmonad's current threading model is a bit lacking (and so is dzen's). However, you can start a separate process that periodically polls your music player and then use one of the dzen multiplexers (e.g. [dmplex](http://dzen.geekmode.org/dwiki/doku.php?id=dzen%3amultiplexer)) to combine the output from the two processes.

You may also want to look into [xmobar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmobar) and [taffybar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/taffybar), which both have better threading stories than dzen does.

With regards to why your proposed `TChan` solution doesn't work properly, you might want to read the sections "Conventions", "Foreign Imports", and "The Non-Threaded Runtime" at [my crash course on the FFI and gtk](http://dmwit.com/gtk2hs), keeping in mind that xmonad currently uses GHC's non-threaded runtime. The short answer is that xmonad's main loop makes an FFI call to Xlib that waits for an X event; this call blocks all other Haskell threads from running until it returns.